# Cannot convert value of type 'DataResponse<String>' to expected argument type 'DataResponse<Any>'

Tags: swift, request, response, completionhandler

Here is my code

```
  Alamofire.request(model.mainURL, method: model.requestMethod, parameters: model.bodyData, encoding: model.encoding, headers: model.headers).responseString {(response) in

            parser.decodeRequest(response: response, completionHandler: {(decodeResponse, error) in
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

                self.completionBlock?(decodeResponse, error)
 })
```

And I have an error like this

`Cannot convert value of type 'DataResponse<String>' to expected argument type 'DataResponse<Any>'`

When I try to parse my response here

```
  parser.decodeRequest(response: response, completionHandler: {(decodeResponse, error) in
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
```

I know that if to change responseString on responseJSON the error will fixed, but I need exactly responseString and don't know how to make it for parser with completionHandler

Comment: post code of parser

Comment: It will give error because it's a string type. Try to type cast the response from string to Any

Comment: Did my answer work? I find the fact that you can't use `responseJSON` very strange. Is the response not JSON at all?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `map` method on `DataResponse`:

```
Alamofire.request(model.mainURL, method: model.requestMethod, parameters: model.bodyData, encoding: model.encoding, headers: model.headers).responseString {(response) in

    parser.decodeRequest(response: response.map { $0 as Any }, completionHandler: {(decodeResponse, error) in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

        self.completionBlock?(decodeResponse, error)
    })
```